# only Last Row is being Updated BY chaning data set value in CustomListView

Tags: android, android-widget

In the above piece of code i`m trying to update Imageresource in customListview using simpleadapter here the problem is whenever i Notifychngedataset() it update only Last row

```
                    public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
     private ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> my;  
    ArrayList<String> ImageList;


              /** Variable Declaration For Items Parsed from TwiterJson*/

        private final String TEXT="text";
       private final String USER="user";
       private final String IMAGEURL="imageurl";
       private final String URL="url";
       private  ListView listView;
       ArrayList<String> textItems;
       ArrayList<String> userlist;
       ArrayList<String> urllist;
       HashMap<String, Object> hm;
         String line;
             private String TAG="HelloWorldActivity";
           private  ProgressBar mProgressBar;
           View view;

            Simpleadapter adapter;



      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

             mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

         // Call the Asynch Activity 
            new AsynchTask().execute();

         }

     /** SimpleAdapater Class Definition*/
         public  class Simpleadapter extends  SimpleAdapter {


    public Simpleadapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


           view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

         final Button mButton=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
         final ImageView mImageview=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        mImageview.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) my.get(position).get(IMAGEURL));

         final int num=position;

         mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse((String) my.get(num).get(URL))));

            }
        });
        return view;
        }


     }


       /**Inner Class for Background Task*/

     private class AsynchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
             URLConnection tc;
         BufferedReader in;
         URL twitter;
     int num=0;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
        try {

             mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,""+e.getMessage());
        }
        }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            twitter = new URL("http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json");
            tc = twitter.openConnection();
            my = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
            ImageList=new ArrayList<String>();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            tc.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
                 Log.e("Length",""+ja.length());
                  for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                            /**Data Insert into the HashMap Object*/
                     hm=new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put(TEXT,jo.getString("text"));
                hm.put(USER,jo.getJSONObject("user").getString("name"));

                hm.put(URL,"http://twitter.com/#!/"+jo.getJSONObject("user").getString("screen_name"));
                hm.put(IMAGEURL, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(HelloWorldActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon));

                ImageList.add(jo.getJSONObject("user").getString("profile_image_url"));
                my.add(hm);



            }

                   }
                   } catch (Exception e) {

                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
        return null;
            }

            @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
             mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
             mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter= new Simpleadapter(HelloWorldActivity.this, my, R.layout.listcontent, 
             new String[]{TEXT,USER}, new int[]{R.id.text2,R.id.text1});
                 listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                 new AsynchTaskForImageLoading().execute();
        }
         }


      /**Method to convert Url to the Bitmap*/


          private Bitmap getDrawable_from_url(String url) {


             try{
                 Bitmap x;
              HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
              connection.setRequestProperty("User-agent","Mozilla/4.0");
           connection.connect();
              InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                  x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                  return x;
              }
                catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG,""+e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }   

        }
     private class AsynchTaskForImageLoading extends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap,Void>
         {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
            }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    for(int i=0;i<ImageList.size();i++){

    publishProgress(getDrawable_from_url(ImageList.get(i)));

    }

        return null;
        }
        @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    for (Bitmap value : values) {
                    hm.put(IMAGEURL,value);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }


            }
            @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);


                }



         }
```

`             }// End of Main Activity Class

i want to update each row`s Imageview but somehow it is updating only Last row of my Listview Recursively i can the changes that is changing images frequently of the last row...

Thanks in Adnavce

Answer (score 1):

you need a loop in your onProgressUpdate():

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
    for (Bitmap value : values) {
        hm.put(IMAGEURL,value);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```